How to parse a String to a HTML object in Dart?
I am trying to easily access an HTML response from a website using Dart CLI.
The main issue is that I can't parse the String response to a DOM/HTML/XML object. I tried with web or html packages but the only supported platform is Web, and I got an error when I imported those packages(Error: Dart library 'dart:js_interop' is not available on this platform.).
Is there a way to parse the HTML string to an HTML object in Dart?
